Unable to setup sub domain with Transip & Azure VM
I trying to setup a subdomain api.mydomain.com in Transip, I can ping mydomain.com but not api.mydomain.com, ping is ICMP is enabled in the VM, This is the scenario:

mydomain.com domain works can ping
api.mydomain.com can't even ping.
both main domain & sub domain point to the same VM.

My api CNAME is somevmw.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com.
My www CNAME is @
Any help will be appreciated.

try to verify  CNAME record for api.mydomain.com is correctly configured and fully propagated and verify that Azure NSG and firewall rules allow ICMP traffic for the VM @MensinBM

Yes, CNAME value is api, correctly configure, ICMP is allow, I am able to ping mydomain.com, but not api.mydomain.com

test the connectivity , try using curl, wget, or access it directly via a browser, as these methods use HTTP/HTTPS instead of ICMP

Fixed & realised, the Primary Server Name is in correct
